# Hello , please someone told me how to install Alamofire in my project

Tags: swift, alamofire

***hello , i just read about Swift Package Manager and how he can install Alamofire in my project  , but i can't understand how i can install it please . thank you !***

Answer (score 0):

Use CocoaPods, since you don't sound very certain on this.

Open up a terminal. Make sure it is in home.

`$ gem install cocoapods -V` if you don't have it.

`cd <your-project-folder>`

`pod init` if you don't have a podfile,

Insert this; `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'`

Go back to the terminal, and `pod install`.

These really are the fundamentals of CocoaPods, (and iOS development in general????) so make sure to go around and learn this if you haven't already.